# HTML form input passed into PHP function argument as array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm filling out a form in HTML, that I want to pass as an array argument to a function in PHP.

Here's how it looks like.

Inside `insert` function later on I'm going to be passing those values to add record into my database table, but for now on there's echoing implemented for debuggnig purposes.

```
<?php

echo '
    Dodaj koncert
    <form action="" method="post">
Nazwa klubu: <input type="text" name="data[0]"><br>
Adres Klubu: <input type="text" name="data[1]"><br>
Nazwa zespolu: <input type="text" name="data[2]"><br>
Ilosc czlonkow: <input type="text" name="data[3]"><br>
Data koncertu: <input type="text" name="data[4]">
<input type="submit" name="dodaj_koncert" value="Dodaj">
</form> ';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    insert(Koncerty, data);
}

function insert($table, $data)
    {
        echo $data[2] . '<br>';
        echo $data[3] . '<br>';
        echo $table;
    }   

?>
```

I'm sure there's something wrong with the `data` that I need to be an array and it's either how I assign values from input form or how I process it. How do I make it work as an array and can read filled form from within the `insert` function?

Comment: switch to if ($_POST) { insert('Koncerty', $_POST); }

Comment: I'm about to add `empty()` checking later on. Does it do that much of a change? If changed to `$_POST` will I not need checking it later on, or what will be happening?

Comment: @Dacto, `Koncerty` is a table in database, while `data` should be PHP array. `$table` will then be executed inside function `insert()` to use this table and insert data from array into it.

Comment: @nobodynoone: Oh. I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '
Dodaj koncert
<form action="" method="post">
    Nazwa klubu: <input type="text" name="data1"><br>
    Adres Klubu: <input type="text" name="data2"><br>
    Nazwa zespolu: <input type="text" name="data3"><br>
    Ilosc czlonkow: <input type="text" name="data4"><br>
    Data koncertu: <input type="text" name="data5">
    <input type="submit" name="dodaj_koncert" value="Dodaj">
</form> ';

// If the submit button field exists then we will insert the data
if (isset($_POST['dodaj_koncert'])) {
    insert('Koncerty', $_POST);
}

// When looking at the form fields from the POST
// You use the name of the field to access it in the $_POST array.
function insert($table, $data)
{
    echo $data['data1'] . '<br>';
    echo $data['data2'] . '<br>';
    echo $table;
}
```